# Counting records in a table given corresponding ID

Tags: sql

This seems like such an easy query to run yet I cannot get it to work and I'm starting to rethink why I chose to tackle this project.

I am trying to find how many records are in a table where an id is identical. For example

```
select productid, productgroup, shelflvl, shelfaisle, Count(Shelfaisle) AS totalaisles
from productlocation
Where productid= productid AND productgroup = 'canned'
Group By productid, productgroup, shelflvl, shelfaisle
```

A product with the same id can be in a different aisle and on a different shelflvl. All I am trying to do is see how many aisles a product is in and I cannot for the life of me get it to work properly.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a product cannot belong to many `productgroup`s.

Remove `Shelfaisle` from `GROUP BY` as this is what you're trying to count.

Also, a `COUNT(DISTINCT Shelfaisle)` would prevent duplicates (if applicable).

Lastly, you don't need a `productid=productid` condition which apparently always yields `true`.

Cut a long story short:

```
select 
  productid, productgroup, shelflvl, Count(distinct Shelfaisle) AS totalaisles
from productlocation
Where productgroup = 'canned'
Group By productid, productgroup, shelflvl
```

Comment: The distinct was my problem. I don't really know why that worked but it did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by the column you are trying to aggregate:

```
select productid, productgroup, Count(Shelfaisle) AS totalaisles
from productlocation
Where productid=productid AND productgroup = 'canned'
Group By productid, productgroup
```

Comment: Even When I do that, I am still getting a returned value of 1 for each row and multiple productid rows. At the top I have a productid shown 3 times, each row has a totalaisles value of 1 where I am needing it to show the product id once and have a total aisles value of 3

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select productid, productgroup, Count(shelfaisle) AS totalaisles
from productlocation
Where productid= productid AND productgroup = 'canned'
Group By productid,productgroup
```

You are adding in additional columns to group by, which means that you can't isolate the product as the thing to count.  You are counting products on specific rows on specific shelflevels, when you only need the product and shelfaisle.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
SELECT productid, shelflvl, MIN(productgroup) AS productgroup,
  COUNT(Shelfaisle) AS totalaisles
FROM productlocation
WHERE productgroup = 'canned'
GROUP BY productid, shelflvl
ORDER BY productid;
```